# How to define a public property in the javascript class?

Tags: javascript, class

With ES5 constructor and prototype approach I can add public (prototype) properties as below:

```
function Utils(){}
Utils.prototype.data = {};

var utils = new Utils();
console.log(utils.data);  //{}
```

The ES6 `class` allows me to define only public methods in the class. I build an app with a class-approach and I don't want to mix constructors and classes features. The working code that I figured out is:

```
class Utils(){
  get _data(){
    const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
    if(!proto._status) proto._data = {};
    return proto._data;
  }
}

const utils = new Utils();
console.log(utils._data); //{}
```

When I call `_data` getter method, it checkes whether the `_data` property exists in the prototype object. If so, it returns it, otherwise it initiates the `_data` property.

Is it a good practice? Is there any other way to do it better?

Comment: Why don't you want to initialize the data property in the ES6 class constructor? Looking at the documentation, it seems like that's the way MDN does it.

Comment: Instance properties are made via `this` (i.e. `this.data = ...`).

Comment: This is a way I thought this could work: https://jsfiddle.net/r2tc1wd7/ . Is this not a good idea @ScottMarcus ?

Comment: @ Dream_Cap if you define `data` in the constructor, then each instance has its own `data` property. I want to 'store' it in the prototype so each instance has only the reference to the same `data` property stored in the class prototype

Answer (score 2):

To make `data` a public instance property:

```
class Utils {
  constructor () {
    this.data = {}
  }
}
```

To make `data` a public static property, get/set is probably the best way:

```
let data = {}
class Utils {
  get _data () {
    return data
  }
  set _data (d) {
    data = d
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the code you provided is your full code or not, but when I run it, it throws an error:

```js
class Utils {
  get _data(){
    const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
    if(!proto._status) proto._data = {};
    return proto._data;
  }
}


/* TEST */
const a = new Utils();
a._data.ok = 'ok';

const b = new Utils();
console.log(b._data.ok);
```

If I understand you correctly, you want all instances of `Utils` to share the same `data` property.

There is a few ways that I can think of to do what you need, but it might "mix constructors and classes features" (I don't really get what you mean by that).

**1: Good ol' ES5 way**

```js
class Utils {}
Utils.prototype.data = {};

/* TEST */
const a = new Utils();
a.data.ok = 'ok';

const b = new Utils();
console.log(b.data.ok);
```

**2: Same as your way, but in it's constructor**

```js
class Utils {
  constructor(){
    if (!this.data) {
      Utils.prototype.data = {};
    }
  }
}

/* TEST */
const a = new Utils();
a.data.ok = 'ok';

const b = new Utils();
console.log(b.data.ok);
```

Though, as the `data` property needs to be shared across instances, I'd suggest you to add the property to its prototype using [`Object.defineProperty` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to make it unwritable and unconfigurable:

```
Object.defineProperty(Utils.prototype, 'data', {
    value: {},
    writable: false,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: false
});
```

This is to ensure the data property cannot be reassigned or deleted, thus minimising the chance of mistakenly reset the data or etc.

I'd recommend the first way (with `Object.defineProperty`) because it is :

1. More foolproof
2. Clearer
3. Easier to maintain